# Mean square derivatives and modifications

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Suppose we have a stochastic process $X$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose there exists a stochastic process $\frac{d X(t)}{d t}$ such that

$$\lim_{h\to0} \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\frac{X(t+h)-X(t)}{h}-\frac{d X(t)}{d t}\right)^2\right]=0$$

Then $\frac{d X(t)}{d t}$ is known as the mean square derivative of $X$. Let $Y$ be a modification of $X$ and let $\frac{d Y(t)}{d t}$ be a mean square derivative of $Y$ (which clearly exists as the existence of mean square derivatives depends on the smoothnes of the covariance function, which a modification does not change). Then is $\frac{d Y(t)}{d t}$ closely related to $\frac{d X(t)}{d t}$ in some way? In particular is $\frac{d Y(t)}{d t}$ also a modification of $\frac{d X(t)}{d t}$ or even indistinguishable from it?

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$X'(t):=\frac{dX}{dt}$$
and, for natural $n$, let
$$X'_n(t):=\frac{X(t+1/n)-X(t)}{1/n}.$$
Similarly define $Y'(t)$ and $Y'_n(t)$. Then for each real $t$
$$X'_n(t)\to X'(t)\quad\text{and}\quad Y'_n(t)\to Y'(t)$$
(in $L^2$ as $n\to\infty$). Also, for each real $t$ and each natural $n$ we have $P(Y'_n(t)\ne X'_n(t))=0$. Hence, the process $Y'(\cdot)$ is a modification of the process $X'(\cdot)$.
$\big($Indeed, for each real $t$ we have
$\|X'(t)-X'_n(t)\|_2\to0$, $\|Y'_n(t)-Y'(t)\|_2\to0$, and $\|X'_n(t)-Y'_n(t)\|_2=0$, whence $$0\le\|X'(t)-Y'(t)\|_2 \\ 
\le\|X'(t)-X'_n(t)\|_2+\|X'_n(t)-Y'_n(t)\|_2+\|Y'_n(t)-Y'(t)\|_2\to0,$$ so that $\|X'(t)-Y'(t)\|_2=0$, so that $P(Y'(t)\ne X'(t))=0$.$\big)$

On the other hand, if $Z(\cdot)$ is **any** modification of the process $X'(\cdot)$, then $Z(\cdot)$ can play the role of $Y'(\cdot)$. So, in general the process $Y'(\cdot)$ is not indistinguishable from the process $X'(\cdot)$.

(See e.g. [Difference between Modification and Indistinguishable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150297/difference-between-modification-and-indistinguishable) for definitions of a modification of a process and of indistinguishable processes.)

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate a bit more on why modifications are preserved in the limit? In particular why $Y'(.)$ is a modification of $X'(.)$ because they are the limits of two sequences that are modifications of each other.

Comment: @123456 : I have elaborated on this.

Comment: Might be an obvious question but is the following correct: if $Z(.)$ is a modification of $X'(.)$, then $Z(.)$ is also a mean square derivative of $X(.)$, because for each $t$, 

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\frac{X(t+h)-X(t)}{h}- Z(t)\right)^2\right] \leq \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\frac{X(t+h)-X(t)}{h}-X'(t)\right)^2\right]+ \mathbb{E}\left[\left(X'(t)-Z(t)\right)^2\right]$$ 

the first term tends to 0 as $h \to 0$ by definition, and the second term is 0 because $X'(t)$ and $Z(t)$ are equal almost surely by the fact that $Z(.)$ is a modification of $X'(.)$?

Comment: @123456 : The inequality in your last comment is correct, but only because the latter expectation is $0$. It is better to use here Minkowski's inequality $\|U+V\|_2\le\|U\|_2+\|V\|_2$ or, alternatively, the inequality $(U+V)^2\le2U^2+2V^2$.Using the latter inequality, you will need the extra factor $2$ on the right-hand side of your inequality.